# Labeling percentage on each sector in sunburst chart in R (and shiny)

Tags: r, shiny, plotly, r-plotly, sunburst-diagram

I want to label the percentage of each sector in a sunburst chart. 
Here what I do in this reproducible example, but this does not seem to be working correctly.

```
  p <- plot_ly(
    labels = c("Eve", "Cain", "Seth", "Enos", "Noam", "Abel", "Awan", "Enoch", "Azura"),
    parents = c("", "Eve", "Eve", "Seth", "Seth", "Eve", "Eve", "Awan", "Eve"),
    values = c(65, 14, 12, 10, 2, 6, 6, 4, 4),
    type = 'sunburst',
    branchvalues = 'total',
    textinfo = "label+percent entry"
  )
  p
```

What do you think is the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

it turned out I was using an older version of R. I just updated my R to the latest version and the problem is solved.